# Is it okay to edit all answers of a question?

Tags: discussion, answers, edits

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989627/help-with-mysql-query-combining-2-tables-with-like-and-or-statement/5989679#5989679) I have answered it, but I also edited 2 other answers in the same question. I have edited the answers of DoXicK and roirodriguez. Now almost in all answers my name is there. So is it okay to edit answers in a question where you have also answered the question? Should I carry on doing this? Or stop doing this kind of thing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the edit was to improve formatting and readability - sure. I can't see anything wrong with that.

Comment: I'm asking this because some people might think that I'm overreacting in answering the question by making my name in all answers.

Comment: @Harry yeah. If someone complains, tell them to take it here

Answer (score 7):

There is nothing wrong in editing other's answers as long as it does not change the meaning of that answer. As Pekka has mentioned, if it is just formatting and readability, it should be fine. The user who originally answered would also realize that your edit is fine and leave it there, or if he feels it changes the actual answer, then he can always rollback your edit.

So you need not worry about such edits from your side.